# Calling FSharp list operators in prefix form

Tags: f#, operators

The following code enables me to pipe a result to the addition operator:

```
let x = 1
x 
|> (+) 3

val x : int = 1
val it : int = 4
```

However I'm not able to use the same approach to add an item to a list:

```
let x = [1]
x
|> (::) 3

x|> (::) 3;;
-----^^

stdin(4,6): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '::' in expression
```

Why is this not a valid construct?